# Dialogflow list does not work on Google Assistant at first time

Tags: artificial-intelligence, dialogflow-es

I am using List response object to display options on the Google Assistant platform to call Webhook Fulfillment

The list options work perfectly when testing on the Dialogflow console. However, when testing through the Google Assistant Simulator or Google Assistant app on a mobile device, the list option does not work on the first try. It works only when selecting an option the second time.

Edited-

[Default welcome intent code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRrwv.png)

[Entities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beMSd.png)

[Intent which call webhook fulfilment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iHii.png)

Comment: every time it is happening?

Comment: yes every time. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: you have to share your code

Comment: Hi @NikhilSavaliya, I just share my code, kindly look into it.

Comment: share your agent so I can debug.

Comment: @NikhilSavaliya, currently it is on draft (testing version)

Comment: @NikhilSavaliya when i remove the List response, then it works fine.